# vue-awesome-swiper para vue 2 no se instala npm ERR! code 255

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, npm

estoy intentado instalar el  `"vue-awesome-swiper": "4.1.1"`  en la consola ejecutó esto `npm install swiper vue-awesome-swiper --save` pero me tira este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi `package.json`, no se si algún paquete este afecto en esto por eso les dejo aqui las depencias, por si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@casl/ability": "4.1.6",
    "@casl/vue": "1.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "2.0.8",
    "@fullcalendar/common": "5.x",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "5.x",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "5.x",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "5.x",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "5.x",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "5.x",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "5.x",
    "@vue/composition-api": "1.3.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "4.0.0",
    "animate.css": "4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "3.23.0",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.21.1",
    "chart.js": "2.9.4",
    "core-js": "3.8.1",
    "echarts": "4.8.0",
    "flatpickr": "4.6.13",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "leaflet": "1.6.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "portal-vue": "2.1.7",
    "postcss-rtl": "1.7.3",
    "prismjs": "1.19.0",
    "uuid": "8.3.2",
    "vee-validate": "3.4.5",
    "vue": "2.x",
    "vue-apexcharts": "1.6.0",
    "vue-autosuggest": "2.2.0",
    "vue-barcode": "1.3.0",
    "vue-chartjs": "3.5.0",
    "vue-cleave-component": "2.1.3",
    "vue-clipboard2": "0.3.1",
    "vue-context": "6.0.0",
    "vue-echarts": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "vue-feather-icons": "5.1.0",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "8.1.6",
    "vue-form-wizard": "0.8.4",
    "vue-good-table": "2.21.0",
    "vue-i18n": "8.22.2",
    "vue-perfect-scrollbar": "0.2.1",
    "vue-prism-component": "1.1.1",
    "vue-quill-editor": "3.0.6",
    "vue-ripple-directive": "2.0.1",
    "vue-router": "3.4.9",
    "vue-select": "3.11.2",
    "vue-slider-component": "3.2.11",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "4.1.1",
    "vue-toastification": "1.7.11",
    "vue-tour": "1.5.0",
    "vue-tree-halower": "1.8.3",
    "vue2-leaflet": "2.5.2",
    "vuedraggable": "2.24.3",
    "vuex": "3.6.0"
  }
```

el proyecto es un poco grande, por eso tengo varias dependias instaladas, algunas si ya no las uso pero no si eso afecte mucho al momento de instalar porque no me sale ningun error de versión o algo así

Comment: me parece que es ``install swiper vue-awesome-swiper --save-dev`` para instalar como dependencia de desarrollo, o simplemente ``install swiper vue-awesome-swiper`` para instalar como dependencia del proyecto

Comment: @AgustinG. de ambas maneras me sale ese mismo error. Aunque de echo es dependencia del proyecto

Comment: que dice la documentacion???

Comment: segun leo esta deprectaed: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-awesome-swiper

Comment: deberias de usar `Swiper Vue component`: https://swiperjs.com/vue y lo instalas con: `npm i swiper`

Comment: Gracias, intenté con eso pero ahora me vota muchos errores en consola, voy a ver si puedo resolverlos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya puedo resolverlo, era porque tenia `npm v8.14.0` simplemente tenia que actulizarlo con `npm install -g npm@latest`

Comment: hola te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta